# Content viewable in any browser, except Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

When I view the page content in Chrome browser I don't get to see the content but on any other browser I can view the content. I have attached the page html content in case it might be useful:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="heading">
    Programme Template - {{programmeTemplateCntlr.programmeTemplate.name}}
    <hr/>
</div>
<div data-ng-repeat="runDay in programmeTemplateCntlr.programmeTemplate.selectedRunDays">
    <div class="heading">{{runDay}}</div>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-field="id"><font size="3">Slot Name</font></th>
                <th data-field="name"><font size="3">Start Time</font></th>
                <th data-field="price"><font size="3">End Time</font></th>
                <th data-field="price"><font size="3">Manage Slots</font></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr id="tr_id_1" class="tr-class-1" data-ng-repeat="slot in programmeTemplateCntlr.fetchSlotsForDay(runDay)">
                <td id="td_id_1" class="td-class-1">{{slot.name}}</td>
                <td>{{slot.startTime}}</td>
                <td>{{slot.endTime}}</td>
                <td ng-if-end>
                    <div ng-switch on="{{slot.id}}">
                        <div ng-switch-when="0">
                            <div>
                                <a href="#/programmeTemplate/{{programmeTemplateCntlr.programmeTemplate.id}}/addSlotTemplate?startTime={{slot.startTime}}&endTime={{slot.endTime}}">
                                    <button class="btn button-details col-sm-4" type="button">
                                        Add Slot
                                    </button>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div ng-switch-default>     
                            <div>                                               
                                <a class="btn btn-edit" href="#/programmeTemplate/{{programmeTemplateCntlr.programmeTemplate.id}}/editSlotTemplate/{{slot.id}}">Edit</a> 
                                <a class="btn button-details" href="" data-ng-click="programmeTemplateCntlr.fetchSlotTemplateById(slot.id)">Details</a>                     
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <hr/>
    <br/>
</div>
<div data-ng-include="programmeTemplateCntlr.slotTemplateModalURL"></div>
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-3">
        <a href="#/viewProgrammes"><button class="btn button-details btn-block" type="submit">Done</button></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have a look in the dev console and see if there are any errors

Comment: Check dev tools (F12 key) for errors

Comment: You're missing the closing div for .container; either that or you're missing the closing div for .heading? Either way, there's a closing div missing.

Comment: Is that really all the code? No `<html>` or `<head>` or `<body>` tags? No CSS or script? Because in my Chrome, I can see the content.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. There is indeed an error on the dev console, will look into it then give feedback

Comment: this is the error message that I am getting:  TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '0' of 762
    at Object.copy (angular.js:835)
    at success (programmeService.js:106)
    at angular-resource.js:626
    at processQueue (angular.js:13171)
    at angular.js:13187
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:14384)
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:14200)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:14489)
    at done (angular.js:9646)
    at completeRequest (angular.js:9836)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:11594